# Sum values ​of SASS variables with var() function

Tags: css, sass

I need to add two variables that come from a SASS file in another importing them with `var()` function.

I have a `root.module.scss` file with the following content:

```
:root {
    --app-padding: 16px;
    --header-height: 72px;
}
```

And another `home.module.scss` file where I need to add the variables defined in the previous `:root` pseudo-class:

```
.home {
    padding-top: var(--app-padding) + var(--header-height); // <-- this doesn't work, obviously
}
```

I have also tried adding the variables inside the `var()` function but it doesn't work either and it gives me a compilation error:

```
.home {
    padding-top: var(--app-padding + --header-height);
}
```

This concatenates the text strings but does not sum the defined values. I have tried to transform the `var()` variables to SASS variables with the `$` character but this does not work either.

Any crazy ideas how I could do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution and share it here in case anyone needs it.

In order to perform arithmetic operations with imported variables with the `var()` function, we can use the `calc()` function. For example:

```
.home {
    padding-top: calc(var(--app-padding) + var(--header-height));
}
```